# Add fields in all documents of a collection - MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud9

I'm having difficulty with the syntax for adding a new field across all documents in a MongoDB collection. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

For example, I would like to add an empty Array to all documents in a collection called 'cats':

```
db.cats.updateMany({}, {$set: {images: []}});
```

It returns the following in AWS Cloud9 command line and doesn't update in MongoDB Atlas documents:

```
MongoDB Enterprise **db**-shard-0:PRIMARY> db.cats.updateMany({}, {$set: {images: []}});
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 0, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

I'm using MongoDB shell version v3.6.3 (however my Server version is 4.2.8)

Comment: Syntax looks fine. Is it possible the collection is empty?

Comment: `"matchedCount" : 0` means the query part did not match any documents.  Is that the right database?

Comment: The problem might have been because I submitted the query from within the Cats collection. I typed :show dbs, use <database>, show collections, use cats and then submitted the query. By going one level up it all worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use empty selector, and set a multi flag to true (last param) to update all the documents

```
db.getCollection('cats').update(
  {},
  { $set: {"images": []} },
  false,
  true
)
```